# Using HashMap in a CommandExecutor

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Im trying to use a HashMap in a CommandExecutor on my plugin, in order to save the info of some blocks that are changed to then, undo the changes. But, when I save the block Types and location to change then later with another command, the hashmap is empty.
This is my code:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String s, String[] arg) {

    public Map<Location, Material> bloques = new HashMap<>() ;

    if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "This command can only be executed by players.");
        return true ;
    }if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("column")) {
        int x = player.getLocation().getBlockX() ;
        int y = player.getLocation().getBlockY() ;
        int z = player.getLocation().getBlockZ() ;
        for (int j=0 ; j<=2 ; j++) {
            for (int i = Integer.parseInt(arg[0]); i > 0; i--) {
                Material b = player.getWorld().getBlockAt(x+j-1, y + 2+ i, z).getType() ;
                bloques.put(player.getWorld().getBlockAt(x+j-1, y + 2+ i, z).getLocation(),b ) ;
                player.getWorld().getBlockAt(x+j-1, y + 2+ i, z).setType(Material.getMaterial(arg[1].toUpperCase()));

            }
        }
        return true ;
    }
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("undo")){

        for (Location w: bloques.keySet()) {
            player.getWorld().getBlockAt(w).setType(bloques.get(w));
             player.sendMessage(bloques.get(w).toString());
        }
        return true ;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The data is being stored when the command "column" is executed, but then if you try to access the map, it is empty.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are declaring the Map inside the `onCommand` method so everytime you enter the method it creates a new instance of the map which will be empty.

To solve this, simply move your Map declaration outside of the method.